# Jquery/Ajax form Post data is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I'm not expert with Jquery. I've built a 4 steps html form like

```
<form id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset id="publish1" data-check-id="1">
        //some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="publish2" data-check-id="2">
        //some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="publish3" data-check-id="3">
        //some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="publish4" data-check-id="4">
        <input type="submit" class="submit action-button pull-right top-35" value="Publish"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and after writing some Jquery validation in my .js file, I've tried to pass my data to a php file through ajax. My `formData` function looks like this:

```
<script>
    function formData() {
        var serializedValues = jQuery("#msform").serialize();
        var form_data = {
            action: 'ajax_data',
            type: 'post',
            data: serializedValues,
        };
        jQuery.post('mypath/insert.php', form_data); //where data should be sent
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Searching around I've tried to build the php file receiving data with this structure:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    post_things();
    return true;
}

function post_things() {
    $title = trim($_POST['form_title']);
    // where form_title is the input[name] of what I want get, serialised into jquery serializedValues variable
    //other similar inputs
    //do something with $title and other $variables
}
?>
```

I've initialized validation and ajax functions doing something as following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        msform_init(); //this validate form step by step (it's working!)
        $('#msform').submit(function (event) {
            if (form_completeCheck() && true) { //This check if something empty
                formData();
                if (formData() && true) {
                    window.location.replace("//some redirection to success");
                } else {
                    window.location.replace("//some redirection to failure");
                }
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click on submit I got redirected to a page where the url is mypath? ALL_MY_DATA_SERIALISED.
Where is my error? I can't see it due to my ignorance. Is in the jquery/ajax functions, in the php file or in my html?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: missing `form_completeCheck()` function in your code, because of which `formData()` isa not called, @XiLab

Comment: form should be like  method="post" for get data in post and  method="get" for get data in uri 
 <form method="post" name="form-name" action="" >

Comment: That is because in case of validation success you are not preventing the default action

Comment: `A`jax is asynchronous and you're getting return 'true' before it is executed properly.

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya `$.post()` will set the method to post whether it's not set on the html form

Comment: Thanks guy, each of these helps has been precious for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do `event.preventDefault()` in the top of your event listener:

```
$('#msform').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();        
  if(form_completeCheck() && true){ //This check if something empty
    formData();
    if(formData() && true){
        window.location.replace("//some redirection to success");
    } else {
        window.location.replace("//some redirection to failure");
    }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Script**

```
<form id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_action"/>
    <fieldset id="publish1" data-check-id="1">
    //some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="publish2" data-check-id="2">
    //some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="publish3" data-check-id="3">
    //some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="publish4" data-check-id="4">
    <input type="button" id="do_action" class="submit action-button pull-right top-35" value="Publish"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#do_action").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:$("#msform").serialize();
        url:'<<php script url>>',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**php script**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action'])){
        post_things($_POST);
        return true;
    }
    function post_things($request){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($request);
        echo "</pre>";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get redirected is because you are submitting the form.

Since in your `<form id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">` you define no action it is submitted to itself.

You must prevent form from submitting using preventDefault().

```
 $('#msform').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); //Add this line
   ..............
```