# How to send array textbox name to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good day mam / sir I am a newbie programmer who want to know how to pass an array textbox/dropbox name to ajax?

I know my code is incorrect. Please can anybody help me. I know that you undestand the output i would like to show.

this is my  sample code:

HTML

```
<select name="departmentmontask1[]" id="departmentmontask11">
<option value="0">Select Department</option>
<option value="0">Select Department</option>
<option value="0">IT</option>
<option value="0">HRM</option>
<option value="0">WAREHOUSE</option>
</select>

<input class="submitbstyle" type="button" name="submitb" onclick="submitform()" value="SUBMIT">
```

JS

```
function submitform()
{
var hospital1 = document.getElementsByName("departmentmontask1").value;

var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("hospital", hospital1);
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'testjsarray.php', true);

          xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
              var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
              console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
            }
          };

          xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status == 200) {

                alert(this.response);

            };
          };

          xhr.send(fd)
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$departmentmon1 = $_POST['departmentmontask1'];

$depmonval1 = array();

foreach($hospitalmon1 as $key1 => $val1)
{
    $depmonval1[] = $val1;
    $depmoncount1 = $depmoncount1 + 1;
}

for($x=0;$x<$depmoncount1;$x++)
{
    echo $depmonval1[$x];
}
?>
```

Comment: Use jquery's serialize method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717771/jquery-ajax-form-post-data-is-not-working/36717947#36717947

Comment: sir the sample textbox on the question you send is not an array field?

Comment: review answer @shiro jacinto

Answer (score 0):

I think in the html you should assign different values to the options
In the php after the assignment you never use the $departmentmon1 variable.
Also the second for can be switched to a foreach getting rid of the $depmoncount1 variable

Answer (score 0):

HTML Form

```
<form class="form" id="f1" >
    <input name="f1_inp_1" value="1">
    <input name="f1_inp_2" value="2">
    <select name="f1_inp_3[]" multiple>
        <option value="f1_val1">f1_val1</option>
        <option value="f1_val2">f1_val2</option>
        <option value="f1_val3">f1_val3</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button id="fire2">Fire2</button>
```

Jquery

```
$("#fire2").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_response.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:$("#f1").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
?>
```